# VDI setup from any OS (e.g. Windows) to Linux machines

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, desktop-environment, cloud-computing, virtual-desktop

The goal is to setup a set of remote VMs on a hypervisor to act as developer machines which can be accessed from any client (windows/linux). A similar setup can be seen via citrix

The ideal scenario is any machine can be commissioned on the hypervisor and then seamlessly connected to a client with full access to the graphical interfaces as well (not just the shell)

I've looked at VMware and Citrix solutions and looking for something open-source instead. In terms of hypervisors I've found xcp-ng which fits the bill. The real missing piece is the remote desktop setup. so far I've only found x2go to be a reasonable implementation but it has its flaws.

The ideal outcome would be similar to running a VM locally (e.g. in virtualbox/vmware) and getting a full fledged desktop access, I would like to achieve this via a remote server